# Is it incorrect to end a sentence with the word "pri"?

Tags: word-order

For example:

> 1. Mi ne povas decidi kio(n) paroli pri. (not sure about the accusative)
> 2. Mi ne povas decidi kion priparoli.

I've said something similar to #1 before not knowing whether it was okay or not. Someone pointed out to me that it probably would be better to say #2, but he wasn't completely sure either, as we are both newer Esperantists.

So, are either of these even correct?  Is it wrong to end a sentence with the word *pri*?  Is there a better way to say something like this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's a clear anglicism. Some people from scandinavian countries also sometimes speak like that, because their languages also know these grammar structures. But in Esperanto it is clearly wrong. A preposition (PMEG terminology "rolvorteto") stands *before* the noun or pronoun.

So the correct sentence is:

> Mi ne povas decidi pri kio paroli.

Alternatively you can use the preposition as a prefix, which is inparticularly popular for *pri*:

> Mi ne povas decidi kion priparoli.

Comment: I am Scandinavian, and I made that mistake just yesterday, so I can definitely verify that part!

Answer (score 8):

No. 1 is incorrect. No. 2 is okay but evades the problem by using a different verb.

Your intention is probably:

> *Mi ne povas decidi, pri kio paroli.*

A preposition cannot appear at the end of a sentence (except of course for sentence fragments like *Ĝis!*). This can sometimes be fixed by adding *-e* to make an adverb:

> *Mi parolis anstataŭ**e**.*

In your sentence, the thing you are deciding must appear straight after *decidi*, but without severing the connection to the verb; I added a comma to make it clearer. And of course if you don't like how it sounds, you could just say something like:

> *Mi ne povas decidi la temon de mia parolado.*

Answer (score 5):

**My** opinion is that this is an English grammar rule in an Esperanto sentence:

> *I cannot decide **what** to talk **about**.*

As far as I know, that is not correct in Esperanto (please correct me if I am wrong). I think prepositions *should* go with the thing they refer to. I would use either option **2** or (maybe because of my native Bulgarian influence):

> *Mi ne povas decidi pri kio paroli.*

Comment: “(please correct me if I am wrong)” → I think you are right, looking at other answers and my own *lingva sento*.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that prepositions are, by definition, in the pre-position. That means they need to come before a word. (English bends that rule a lot, but Esperanto does not.)

It's not just pri, but this is true for all Esperanto prepositions. They should never be used at the end of a sentence.

Here is a list of prepositions and other particles that you should never find at the end of a sentence.

*pri, super, trans, post, kontraŭ, de, inter, ĉirkaŭ, ĉe, antaŭ, post, sub, apud, preter, per, malgraŭ, dum, krom, for, por, pro, el, en, sur, ekster, super, per, po, ol, tra, ĝis, al, sub, kun, sen, laŭ, krom, anstataŭ, ekster, malgraŭ, da*

The only possible exception is *da* - at that only in informal spoken Esperanto when there are no children or vulnerable adults within earshot.