# De kio “saluton” estas la rekta objekto?

Tags: etymology, language-evolution

"Saluton" finiĝas per "n" sekve saluton estas rekta objekto, sed la rekta objekto de kio?

"Saluton" ends with an "n" thus it's a direct object, but the direct object of what?

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you’d like some corrections to your grammar you could change the title to “De kio “saluton” estas la rekta objekto?”. In Esperanto the preposition [always goes before the thing it is referencing](http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1282/is-it-incorrect-to-end-a-sentence-with-the-word-pri), even if the thing is a question word.

Comment: And another small mistake: "finas kun"  should be "finiĝas per". "Fini" is a transitive verb. "Mi finas mian laboron" vs. "Saluton finiĝas".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Saluton* is simply a shorthand way of saying the complete sentence:

> Mi donas al vi saluton!

The reason for the accusative ending is to denote that the greeting is the object, of which I am giving to you.

You'll see the same pattern with other things, such as `Dankon` and `Bonan matenon`.

[PMEG has further explanation](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/frazospecoj/mallongigitaj_frazoj.html#i-tfd) if you want to read more about it (in Esperanto).

Comment: aŭ «mi ofertas»?